# Use CSS to format date/time or percent value?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use CSS to format a date using a specific format, e.g. YYYY/MM/DD, or MM/DD/YYYY, with or without time?

Also can a number be formatted as a percentage value with 2 decimals, e.g. 5.4321987 displayed as 5.43%

I could probably use JavaScript but I want to know first if it's possible to use CSS to do this?

Comment: CSS has no support for such formatting for any type: it cannot process the 'value' of text in HTML.

Comment: Looks like CSS is not really an option.
For those looking for a Javascript/jquery solution, https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/ seems to be good.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to format dates with only CSS. This includes changing year/month/day display order, the separators between the dates, showing/hiding leading zeroes, display 4-digit years as 2-digit years (e.g. 1994 becomes '94), can be extended to include hours/minutes/seconds/etc., and even works inline within a paragraph. It allows static HTML to be reformatted later just with CSS. This provides great flexibility, doesn't require learning Javascript, and I'm using it myself to format dates on Anki cards (which use HTML and CSS).

First some limitations: it won't work on older browsers, it requires modifying the source HTML, and it requires source date leading zeros to be consistent (either always present or always absent), and it's not particularly elegant. If you already know Javascript, that's going to be a more powerful and more elegant solution.

The solution uses a flexbox to allow changing the order of the elements, and puts the date values in HTML custom attributes to be able to be read by the CSS. Click <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> on the example below to see how `day=3`, `month=9`, and `year=1994` is formatted with CSS into `March 09, '94`.

```
<div class="date-wrapper">
  <div class="date-year" val="1994"></div>
  <div class="date-month" val="03"></div>
  <div class="date-day" val="09"></div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Setup for date flexbox */
.date-wrapper {
  align-items: baseline;
  background: #f00;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.date-year,
.date-month,
.date-day {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Set date display order */
.date-year   { order: 3; }
.date-month  { order: 1; }
.date-day    { order: 2; }
.date-suffix { order: 4; }

/* Display dates based on "val" custom attribute in HTML */
.date-year::after,
.date-month::after,
.date-day::after {
  content: attr(val);
}

/* Add separators */
.date-year::before { content: ", "; }
.date-month::before { content: "★"; }
.date-day::before { content: "\00a0"; }   /* \00a0 is a non-breaking space */
.date-suffix::before { content: "★"; }

/* Convert month numbers to month text */
.date-month[ val="1"]:after{ content: "January"; }
.date-month[ val="2"]:after{ content: "February"; }
.date-month[ val="3"]:after{ content: "March"; }
.date-month[ val="4"]:after{ content: "April"; }
.date-month[ val="5"]:after{ content: "May"; }
.date-month[ val="6"]:after{ content: "June"; }
.date-month[ val="7"]:after{ content: "July"; }
.date-month[ val="8"]:after{ content: "August"; }
.date-month[ val="9"]:after{ content: "September"; }
.date-month[val="10"]:after{ content: "October"; }
.date-month[val="11"]:after{ content: "November"; }
.date-month[val="12"]:after{ content: "December"; }

/* Add leading zero to days */
.date-day[val="1"]:after{ content: "01"; }
.date-day[val="2"]:after{ content: "02"; }
.date-day[val="3"]:after{ content: "03"; }
.date-day[val="4"]:after{ content: "04"; }
.date-day[val="5"]:after{ content: "05"; }
.date-day[val="6"]:after{ content: "06"; }
.date-day[val="7"]:after{ content: "07"; }
.date-day[val="8"]:after{ content: "08"; }
.date-day[val="9"]:after{ content: "09"; }

/* Display 4-digit years as 2-digit years (e.g. 1994 becomes '94) */
/* As far as I can tell, doing this fully requires 100 lines of CSS which kinda sucks */
.date-year[val="1990"]:after{ content: "'90"; }
.date-year[val="1991"]:after{ content: "'91"; }
.date-year[val="1992"]:after{ content: "'92"; }
.date-year[val="1993"]:after{ content: "'93"; }
.date-year[val="1994"]:after{ content: "'94"; }
.date-year[val="1995"]:after{ content: "'95"; }
.date-year[val="1996"]:after{ content: "'96"; }
.date-year[val="1997"]:after{ content: "'97"; }
.date-year[val="1998"]:after{ content: "'98"; }
.date-year[val="1999"]:after{ content: "'99"; }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis lacus non risus consectetur aliquet. Duis placerat ac nulla eu 
<span class="date-wrapper">
    <span class="date-year"  val="1994"></span>
    <span class="date-month" val="3"></span>
    <span class="date-day"   val="9"></span>
    <span class="date-suffix"></span>
</span>
lobortis. Integer vulputate, metus eget maximus pretium, nisl orci ultrices 
quam, sit amet rutrum lacus neque vitae turpis.</p>
```

Changing display of numbers into percents is possible with the same search-and-replace technique, but since dates are finite (only 12 months and 31 days to deal with) but numbers are infinite, this is only useful when dealing with numbers in a very small range. For example, if you're only ever changing 3.59 to 3.6%, then it's trivially easy. For anything else, Javascript or other scripting will be far more elegant.

```css
/* Display 3.59 as 3.6% */
.num-to-percent[val="3.59"]::after{ content:"3.6%"; }
```

```html
<span class="num-to-percent" val="3.59"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS cannot accomplish this on older browsers. You'll need to use JavaScript if you want backwards compatibility.

If legacy browsers do not concern you, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60598886/12586904

Answer (score 1):

Css cant be used to formate date. Use php or javascript to do so.

Answer (score -1):

CSS doesn't support date formatting.You cannot format date with css.

Here Let me share alternate option except javascript there is html5 element available which may can help you.

You can use [time-element](https://css-tricks.com/time-element/) for this. This html element will help you to formate and display the date.

**NOTE:** Before using this please make sure and read the browser support of this element If you will use in public html pages.

Comment: `<time>` is an HTML5 tag. There's no CSS that formats dates or times that you can apply to this or any other element. On the link you provided there's no mention of CSS formatting at all.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Sorry I know but I forgot to mention that css doesn't have date formatting concept. I just gave html5 element as an alternate if he is not aware.

Comment: An alternate to what? The OP is asking for CSS, not HTML.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think CSS can't format date or percentage format.

If you want to format date or percentage format, I think it's the best if you use PHP

Comment: Why PHP? Any server-side language that produces HTML could do this, or Javascript could do it on the client.

Comment: Time formatting should be done client-side, since it will take care of the client timezone.